# RouteParams no angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Estou usando o RouteParams no AngularJs

```
$routeProvider.when("/ReciboPagamentoCorretor/:NUMERO_RECIBO", {
    templateUrl: "view/ReciboPagamentoCorretor.html",
    controller: "ReciboPagamentoCorretorController"
})
```

mas na hora do `rootScope`

```
 $http.get(config.BaseUrl + "/auth.php").success(function(inf) {
     if (typeof inf == "object") {
         if (inf.nivel == 1 && $location.path() != "/ContratosCorretor" &&
         $location.path() != "/NovoContratoCorretor" &&
         $location.path()!= "/PagamentosCorretor" &&
         $location.path() != "/ReciboPagamentoCorretor" &&
         $location.path() != "/ContratosPendentesCorretor") {
             $location.path("/ContratosCorretor")
         }
    }
})
```

Ele diz que `location.path() != "/ReciboPagamentoCorretor"` é true e não me deixa acessar a página `/ReciboPagamentoCorretor`

Comment: Mas, qual é o seu objetivo? Eu não sei por que você mencionou o uso de routeParams mas só está utilizando $location. Qual o seu objetivo e qual o problema atual?

Comment: Essa verificação `location.path() != "/ReciboPagamentoCorretor"` é `true`, pois o `$location.path()` que deve estar vindo segundo seu _route_, deve ser algo tipo: `"/ReciboPagamentoCorretor/1"`, onde o numero 1 seria o `:NUMERO_RECIBO` do _route_. Então isso `"/ReciboPagamentoCorretor/1"` é diferente disso `"/ReciboPagamentoCorretor"`. O que você pode tentar fazer para resolver isso é um startWith (começa com) ou alguma expressão regular.